# Problem using SevSegShift library with ESP32 and 74HC595

Tags: c++, esp32, seven-segment-display, shift-register

I'm trying to build a digital clock using ESP32. I cannot use the TM1637 display module because it's too small. So I'm using a generic common anode 4 digit 7 segment display. I used the Arduino [SevSeg](https://github.com/DeanIsMe/SevSeg) library on ESP32 and it worked perfectly. However, it consumed a lot of GPIO pins. Hence I used two 74HC595 registers and connected them exactly as described in the [SevSegShift](https://github.com/bridystone/SevSegShift) library (a fork of SevSeg library but with shift registers), like this: [image]

Unfortunately, when I run the code, I get wrong output. No matter what number or characters I try to display, only the "b" segment of the corresponding digits are turned on, all other segments of all digits are turned off. For ex, if I try to display "1111", only the "b" segment of all digits are turned on, rest all segments of all digits are turned off. As a result only upper half of "1111" is displayed on the 7 segment display.

Here's the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SevSegShift.h>

#define SHIFT_PIN_DS   5 /* Data input PIN */
#define SHIFT_PIN_STCP 19 /* Shift Register Storage PIN */
#define SHIFT_PIN_SHCP 18 /* Shift Register Shift PIN */

SevSegShift sevseg(SHIFT_PIN_DS, SHIFT_PIN_SHCP, SHIFT_PIN_STCP); //Instantiate a seven segment controller object (with Shift Register functionality)




void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {8+2, 8+5, 8+6, 2}; // of ShiftRegister(s) | 8+x (2nd Register)
  byte segmentPins[] = {8+3, 8+7, 4, 6, 7, 8+4, 3,  5}; // of Shiftregister(s) | 8+x (2nd Register)
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false;
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE; 
  bool updateWithDelays = false;
  bool leadingZeros = false;
  bool disableDecPoint = false;

  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);
  

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  sevseg.setNumber(1111, 0);
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
  delay(1);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the circuit layout given above correct? More importantly, does the **SevSegShift** library work with ESP32?

Comment: You said the SevSegShift library worked perfectly.

Comment: Is this C++? You should always tag your question with a language. Also there is an [arduino.se] SE where you might find more subject matter experts.

Comment: @romkey SevSeg and SevSegShift are two different libraries. I got SevSeg working but facing problems with SevSegShift.

Comment: Got it, sorry for my confusion.